# statements in chevrons after class name meaning

Tags: objective-c, class, protocols, abstract-class, objc-protocol

In the section of code below, what exactly does the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` part mean and do? what would it most likely be used for and what would most likely happen if it was removed? (any theoretical example is good)

```
@interface PhoneContentController : ContentController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `PhoneContentController` adopts the ObjC protocol named `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

A protocol is an interface of methods without definition. When the class adopts it, it advertises that it implements the methods declared by the protocol.

This is a common feature in OOD for an abstract type, particularly in languages which use single inheritance only. If you know Java, it's much like `implements UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: OK, and what does that mean? I'm very new to obj-c